# iPhone: Best Practice for Using NSThread to Load Thousands of Images?

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I am trying to load thousands of images using NSThread but the performance is quite slow.

What would be the best practice to use NSThread to download thousands of images?

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: NSThread does not make anything slower by itself. Did you use Shark or Instruments to find where your app is spending CPU cycles?

Comment: Depends what your goal is--is the important thing when all 1,000 images are loaded, or can you figure out which images you need first and show something useful while the other 997 are loading?

Comment: David,I tried the way mentioned by you.I am downloading the some images that are widely used after the applicationLaunch Successfully. I can see that my application performance is definitely increased.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSThread isn't the problem. It sounds like you might be simply overwhelming the iPhone hardware. Remember, a mobile platform has only a fraction of power of even the slowest laptop.

Look at how the photo app has to blur-fade in images at times. Sometimes, it has to do that with thumbnails as well. It can take up to 10-20 seconds to display a graphics intensive web page.

It sounds like you need to rethink your design. Unless you're loading microscopically small images, your simply not going to load "thousands" of them in a timely manner on iPhone hardware. You need to load as you display. Logically chop the images up into groups and then have the user navigate to the group they want and then load only that small group.

Comment: Yeah That's true NSThread wasn't the problem. I once again thought on design and now with new design application looks good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Also consider to use the `NSOperationQueue` to coordinate those downloads. Using the `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` classes you can *schedule* a thousand downloads but make sure that only a certain amount of downloads happen concurrently.

To score bonus points, use the Reachability API to see if the user is on 3G or Wifi and set the number of concurrent downloads based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are downloading images over http I recommend using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framwork. It can easily download html, images and other stuff asynchronous.

But, be careful not to download to many things at the same time. I have read *somewhere* that 10 http connections at the same time should be a good amount. (Somewhere was the AppSales-Mobile project [ReviewUpdater.h](http://github.com/epatel/AppSales-Mobile/blob/master/Classes/ReviewUpdater.h#LID3) value set by jonkean in his [commit](http://github.com/jonkean/AppSales-Mobile/commit/7792f1e7ce94e9fde426069853422c5fc514dc77))